# ¿Cómo puedo pasar variables a un archivo js de react?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un proyecto en Flask (Python) y necesitaba crear en una parte del sitio contenido dinámico y amigable para el usuario. Entonces utilicé REACT para crear un componente que, una vez exportado, inserté en mi sitio al tomar el archivo JS y CSS que genera el proceso build.

Mi duda ahora es cómo hacer para pasarle a ese archivo variables de entorno propias de la aplicación mayor(Flask). Por ejemplo, podría pasarle el nombre del usuario logueado, o un token para generar consultas.

Muchas gracias.